# PDF htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pdf, redirect

I have used the rule below which redirects every PDF file to a single page. What I would like to do is redirect a certain PDF to a certain page instead of every PDF going to one page.

Example: `carolina-application.pdf` redirects to `//carolina-gun-laws.com`

Is it possible to modify the code below to do this?

Place this rule at top of your `.htaccess` (just below RewriteEngine line):

```
RewriteRule ^.+\.pdf$ http://example2.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Please explain what you tried so far. Maybe it would be helpful to read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce

Answer (score 0):

You should place specific redirect rule before generic redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^carolina-application\.pdf$ http://carolina-gun-laws.com/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^.+\.pdf$ http://example2.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Yes thanks, but now here's the problem I have been told that a 301 redirect removes the page from the Google search index, not sure if thats correct. But if it does  it defeats my whole purpose as I need these PDFs to rank in google.

Comment: Other thing I was just made aware of is that redirecting these PDFs is called cloaking, very bad for SEO in fact could have your IP address banned from google searches.

Comment: Your question was not about SEO. It was about how to redirect and that's what I answered. I suggest use `301` to avoid poor SEO. But if you have further SEO queries then raise a new question.